# Ensure that a lambda expression points to an actual property of a class?

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression, .net-4.5

Is there any way to ensure that I can only pass in an expression that points to property on the a class?

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        HelperClass.HelperFunc(() => Bar);
    }
}

public static class HelperClass
{
    public static void HelperFunc(Expression<Func<string>> expression)
    {
        // Ensure that the expression points to a property
        // that is a member of the class Foo (or throw exception)
    }
}
```

Also, if need be, I can change the signature to pass the actual class in as well...

Comment: Shouldn't the parameter be a `Expression<Func<T,string>> expression` where T is either a generic parameter of your helper function, helper class, or a concrete type?

Comment: do you mean at compile time? or at runtime?

Comment: @MarcGravell I would assume at runtime, since he says to throw an exception.

Comment: @MarcGravell CompileTime or RunTime would both be fine... I just want to make sure people aren't passing in bad stuff in the lambda.

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't think this would be possible as a compile time check. Were you simply just asking?

Comment: @m-y I agree - just trying to see what the expectation was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is extension method, which converts lambda to property. If lambda does not points to property, exception is thrown

```
public static PropertyInfo ToPropertyInfo(this LambdaExpression expression)
{
    MemberExpression body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (body != null)
    {
        PropertyInfo member = body.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (member != null)
        {
            return member;
        }
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Property not found");
}
```

Comment: How do I ensure that it's an actual property of that class and not some other class?

Comment: Check if member.DeclaringType == typeof(Foo)